# Unicode CSV Python

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I'm not able to get this right. I've a CSV file which has already encoded characters in it (I made a smaller CSV file to test, but the original is way longer):

Isten H\xe1ta M\xf6g\xf6tt
Sigur R\xf3s
\xd3lafur

I can't get these strings to be decoded. I tried decoding it by simple reading the line and then do line.decode('latin1'), but it doesn't seem to work. When I looked at the raw string, I noticed that the characters are being escaped by an extra backslash. So, I tried to do an unicode-escape on the raw string first before doing the decoding; this also doesn't seem to work. The string stays the way it is (got the extra backslash removed though in the raw string).

When I hard-code a manual list with the example items, then the decoding works and I get the right characters back.

So, I only don't get it to work when I read it in from a CSV file. Anybody has an idea where it goes wrong?

Comment: Is this python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: It's python 2.7

Comment: How did you get that text in the file in the first place? its double encoded.

Comment: It's data that I didn't create myself. Trying to figure out how to get the right text out of it. How come that it comes out fine when I put it manually in a string/list, but don't work when I read it in from a CSV?

Comment: If you put `foo = "Isten H\xe1ta M\xf6g\xf6tt"` in a python script, python unescaped it the same way it converts newlines in `bar = "one\ntwo\nthree\n"`. If you put that exact same text in a csv file, that's not parsed by the python compiler and no unescaping is done. That's what the `string_escape` encoding is for. It seems like somebody used python to print a list of strings and then copy/pasted them to the file. Don't do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters have different representations in-memory and in a file. A string can be encoded in several ways including a `latin-1` encoding or `utf-8` but in this case where we see a literal `\xf6`, what we have is a string that's been escaped. We can fix that by decoding the escapes

```
>>> print open('data.csv').readline().decode('string_escape')
Isten H�ta M�g�tt
```

But that only gets us half way, we are still encoded. Now a double decode

```
>>> print open('data.csv').readline().decode('string_escape').decode('latin1')
Isten Háta Mögött
```

Got it! The problem is in whatever wrote the file.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> mystring = 'Sigur R\xf3s'
>>> print mystring
Sigur R�s
>>> print mystring.decode('latin-1')
Sigur Rós
```

Seems to work fine on python 2.7, can you show some code and the error it generates?

Comment: This is what I tried and then it works. I can't get it to work when reading from a CSV